# Two button confirmations - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, client-side, confirmation

Currently I have a submit button that pops up a confirmation that allows the form data to be processed or not.

I need my other button on my form page called "Cancel" to have the same action. How could I expand this code to add a second confirmation to the same form?

these are my buttons on the form :

[image]

And this is my current code that works :

```
 </script>
        <script>
            $(document).on('submit', "#signinform", function(e)
            {
                if (!confirm("By clicking 'OK' you will be placed in queue! Please take a seat."))
                {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return;
                }
            });
        </script>
```

> just to add on :

The submit is a submit BUTTON. the Cancel is just a href with a border around it.

also again

This works at the moment for just the submit button.

I need my other button on the form called "Cancel" to do the samething, as in if you hit Ok your submission data will be deleted, and then you will be returned back to the form. If you hit cancel then you will remain on the page.

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: Just for the record: The previous solution used jquery's dialog method like `$(...).dialog({buttons:{Confirm:-handler-, Cancel:-handler-}})` not `$(document).ready()`

Comment: You need to define what you want the cancel button to do, you can't just copy the confirm button and expect it to work.

Comment: I need the Cancel to do the same thing as the Submit. I have two buttons on my form, to submit, and to Cancel. Submit will ask for an Ok before submitting or a cancel. The form cancel button will for a confirmation or a cancel before ending you submission. So I need them to do the same thing.

Comment: Updated the OP to be more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you simply need something like

```
$(document).on('click', "#cancelButtonID", function(e)
{
    if (!confirm("By clicking 'OK' you cancel the submission and the form is cleared."))
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    }
    else {
        //Clear the form or perform whatever actions are needed
    }
});
```

I think however that you may want to replace your cancel link with a proper `<input type="reset">` button, as that will clear the form automatically when you let the default action happen. Then you should be able to get rid of the `else` section above.

Comment: added an update to the OP, and still nothing, I understand that I didn't have an JS event handler like dialog() there I added that and I still get noting to the code?

Comment: Do the buttons not work as expected or don't you even get the dialog?

Comment: I updated my OP to make it more clear what I need it to do. Hopefully that can clear some stuff up.